# Xml file parsing prolog error

Tags: java, xml, firefox

i have an xml file which starts < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

..... and did the dom xml parsing in java. If i compile and run via the Tomcat manager in my Firefox browser version 4.0, that program executes succesfully. But if I try the same in my Firefox browser latest version 12.0 or IE 8, then it causes the following error.

SAX Exception : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.I have searched the problem in internet and somebody said add a space between utf-8 and the prolog.I have tried that too. But still the problem exist. So any one who gives suggestion would help me.

Comment: Can you open the xml in IE 8 directly... does that work or gives error.. ?

Comment: u may be forget to add ? at starting because latest browser use xhtml. so it is very strict with tag. i.e. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> refer link:http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html

Comment: I can open the file at the browser IE 8 as well as Firefox 12.0

Comment: I already added ?xml version="1.0" in my xml file but still that does not work

Comment: I see a space character between `<` and `?`. Please try removing that.

Comment: I give a space only here because if i remove that space, then the data inside <> is not displaying here

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and the reason was just a simple mistake as I did not provide the file path to the `parse` method.

Having a correct file path solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is space before < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> this line